# Как оптимальнее всего реализовать шифрование трафика между клиентом и сервером на java

Tags: java, безопасность, шифрование

Добрый день!
Есть клиент и сервер, оба написаны на java. Работают через api get запросы, клиент отправляет запрос и получает ответ в json. Клиент имеет открытый исходный код, общедоступный. Как 
 по вашему мнению оптимальнее всего в данном случае зашифровать между ними трафик и гарантировано защититься от mitm-атаки?

Comment: ssl сокеты использовать

Answer (score 3):

Используйте TLS и ни в коем случае не пытайтесь изобретать собственный протокол.